# concatenate / interpolate a concatenated/interpolated variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var $newDiv = $(`<div style='background: ${arr_rainbow[k]};'></div>`)

element.append('<td style="width:${td.eq(k).width()}px;"></td>')
```

how do I insert $newDiv into `<td></td>`? 
I tried

```
element.append('<td style="width:${td.eq(k).width()}px;">${$newDiv}</td>')
```

and it returns a string of [object Object]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $newDiv = `<div style='background: ${arr_rainbow[k]};'></div>`
element.append('<td style="width:${td.eq(k).width()}px;">${$newDiv}</td>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try

`element.append('<td style="width:${td.eq(k).width()}px;">${$newDiv.html()}</td>')`